# NodeJS Cannot GET endpoint - returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js application that suddenly stopped working. It calls a local endpoint that does exist - calling it in Chrome returns valid json - but suddenly started returning Cannot GET /api/clientspopulate when called using the Node.js http module:

```
var http = require("http");

http.get({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  path: '/api/clientspopulate',
  port: 3000,
  agent: false,  // create a new agent just for this one request
  headers: {
    accept: '*!/!*'
  }
}, function (res) {
  console.log(res.statusCode);

  var body = '';
  res.on('data', function (d) {
    body += d;
  });

  res.on('end', function (d) {
    //clientspopulate returns json structure of all clients and their child properties.
    var clients = JSON.parse(body);

    //...rest of code...
```

Like I said this used to work, but suddenly started returning Cannot GET and returning statusCode:404, even though it is reachable via browser.

Comment: Do you have documentation for `accept: '*!/!*'`?  I haven't seen exclamation points used for that before.  Additionally, does the endpoint that you are making the request to acknowledge anything?  Is it also a node server?  Can you post its endpoint definition and try logging to see if it ever enters the endpoint callback?

Comment: I took out the !'s and made it the conventional */* and same behavior. For logging in the endpoint, it never hits it, though I can see the logging if I make the http://localhost:3000/api/createpopulate call in a web browser.  Another odd thing is that the Node call DOES work for the base url (http://localhost:3000 returns HTML), but any call to any valid path beyond localhost:3000 404s yes it's calling a node server